# Using "already" in Simple Aspect

Tags: present-perfect, adverbial-phrases, perfect-aspect

I've found out an interesting fact. We could also use the adverbial modifier "already" not only in Perfect Aspect. We can do it, if we are amazed by something haven't been expected before? Like in the next sentence:

```
"When I came back home they were already sleeeping".
```

Comment: Yes, you can use *already* there, but it doesn't have anything to do with something being unexpected or amazing.

Comment: @stangdon: I think there usually *is* a (relatively weak) implication of something being "unexpected" (or at least, "unexpectedly ***early***") when it's reported as having ***already*** happened. If only because whenever we say something has "already happened", we're almost always implying this is in contrast to the possibility that it *might not have happened **yet*** (or might ***never*** happen).

Comment: How is this an "interesting fact"? It seems pretty mundane to me. What's perhaps more interesting is the use of *already* as an intensifier: "Will you get in the car already? We have to go!"

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Hm, maybe - I'm thinking about the difference between, say, "When I got to the car they were inside" vs "when I got to the car they were *already* inside".  Maybe it weakly implies something unexpected at a semantic level...

Comment: @stangdon: In the car context we can probably assume that if ***already*** is included then the speaker always thought it likely that they would *eventually* get in the car - but the implication is he didn't expect this outcome until *later*. On the other hand, if it's *not* included, this could be in a context where the speaker is actually astonished to find them in the car (because it's *his* car, for which he's got the only set of keys, perhaps! :), and *that* sense of "unexpected" wouldn't always be properly conveyed if he'd included the word ***already***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree with you about "already" meaning "unexpectedly early" or "earlier than expected."

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you response has been of help for me again) I appreciate it

Comment: @Robusto ESL books almost always show the adverbs "already" and "yet" as exclusively associated with the present perfect, so it's no wonder that the OP found this use new (although we all know it's widespread in the language).

Comment: @AnthonyVoronkov I know for a fact that many site members consider saying "thank you" as noise that should be avoided, but I really appreciate your gratefulness as it shows not only how polite you are but how much you value every single response. You don't need to say thank you every time you get an answer, but I personally find it very nice of you.

Comment: @Gustavson, I'll follow your recomendations)

Comment: @Gustavson, would you be so kind as to answer my topic: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122086/using-past-perfect-and-past-simple-making-emphasis?noredirect=1#comment246036_122086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it's (already?! :) been deleted by the time you read this, I'll just reproduce here the key point made in [@Gustavson's comment...](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122073/using-already-in-simple-aspect?noredirect=1#comment246267_122073)

> *ESL books almost always show the adverbs **already** and **yet** as exclusively associated with the present perfect, so it's no wonder that the OP found this use new.*

Before reading that I couldn't really see why OP thought it was somehow "unusual" to use ***already*** with "non-perfect" verb forms. But thinking about it now I realise this is because ***already*** (and its "counterpart" ***yet***) usually imply some kind of *juxtaposition, contrast* between two different times.

OP's example probably doesn't reflect actual "amazement" that they should sleeping so early - but in general, *X has **already** happened* implies that X wasn't *expected* to happen ***yet*** (not until ***later***). Just as *X has **not yet** happened* tends to imply it was expected to have happened ***earlier***.

The implication of the above is that whenever we use ***already*** or ***yet***, it's quite likely the context will encourage us to use a "perfect" verb form for *one* of the two different times being juxtaposed/contrasted. That's simply because [as Wikipedia points out...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar))

> *The perfect tense or aspect (abbreviated perf or prf) is a verb form that indicates that an action or circumstance occurred **earlier than the time under consideration,** often focusing attention on the resulting state rather than on the occurrence itself.* (Italics mine.)

So although in ***semantic*** terms, the primary reason for using perfect forms is usually *focusing attention on the resulting state*, ***syntactically*** it often turns out that we want to refer to *something that happened before it was expected* using a perfect form. But this is just a loose tendency caused by the interaction of semantics and syntax, not a grammatical principle as such.

---

I'll also just make the point here that because native speakers tend to prefer simpler tenses where they have a choice, you're as likely to hear ***I already did it*** where learners might think ***I have already done it*** is somehow "more correct". As ever, when it comes to perfect verb forms, the best advice for learners is to look for ways to *avoid* them, rather than ways to use them more often.